# Store background color in a variable

Tags: javascript

How do I store the background color of one div in a variable and later use that variable to change the background color of another div using only javascript?

```
var b2 = document.getElementById("box2"),
b3 = document.getElementById("box3");

function d2(){
document.getElementById("box3").style.backgroundColor = b2.style.backgroundColor;
document.getElementById("box2").style.backgroundColor = b3.style.backgroundColor;
}
```

I made two boxes with color red to box2 and green to box3. Then tried interchanging their colors by storing their colors in a variable and assigning the color of the variable to the divs but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This code just worked fine for me. Thanks for the help.

```
function getStyle(x,styleProp) {
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
function d2(){
    b2 = document.getElementById("box2")
    b3 = document.getElementById("box3")
    y1 = getStyle ( b3, 'background-color' )
    document.getElementById("box3").style.backgroundColor = getStyle ( b2, 'background-color' )
    document.getElementById("box2").style.backgroundColor = y1
}
```

Comment: I'd start by looking at how to get the background color of a div, and then set up a variable using that method. e.g. `var color = $(div).css ...` and so on. But without any proof, like @PA. asked for, there's not much we can (or will) do.

Comment: Thanks PA and eric for suggesting the edit. I'm new here so didn't know much.

Comment: @user3755774.... I have updated the fiddle try that one

Answer (score 1):

Created a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/JXyx2/

***JS:***

```
var storedColor = $('#one').css('background-color');

// set stored color two other div
$('#two').css('background-color', storedColor);
```

Comment: OP didn't ask for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="d1" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid;background-color:red"></div>
    <div id="d2" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid;"></div>


    <button id="click"  type="button">click to change the color</button> 
    <script>

    var color=$("#d1").css("background-color");

    $("#click").click(function()
    {
        $("#d2").css("background-color",color);
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: OP didn't ask for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

By using only `javascript` try this one

```
var divColor = document.getElementById("id").style.backgroundColor; 
                                            //you get the color of div
```

then apply this to another div by using:

```
document.getElementById("id1").style.backgroundColor=divColor;
```

**update**

```
 <div id="box2">
         <button type="button" class="d2" onClick="d2(this)">down</button>
        </div>
    <div id="box3">
        </div>

    function d2(element)
{
        var c = window.getComputedStyle(element.parentElement).backgroundColor;
        document.getElementById("box3").style.backgroundColor=c;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUsz7/6/)

Comment: Thanks. Also I wanted to know how can I interchange the colors of the 2 divs?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this

Comment: I tried your suggestion as well but that isn't working either. Here is the fiddle for that:
http://jsfiddle.net/qUsz7/3/

Comment: Going by your code I lose the color of the 2nd div. My main purpose was to interchange their colors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="d1" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid;background-color:red"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid;"></div>


<button id="click"  type="button"  onclick="change()">click to change the color</button> 
<script>

var color=document.getElementById("d1").style.backgroundColor;


function change()
{
    document.getElementById("d2").style.backgroundColor=color;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Also I wanted to know how can I interchange the colors of the 2 divs?